# Use Apple Wireless Keyboard for PC and Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, wifi, switching, windows

I need a wireless keyboard and mouse that I can switch between my MacBook Pro and PC.

I was looking at the Apple Wireless Keyboard, but I'm not sure if I can change from PC to Mac usage easily enough.

Does anyone have a similar setup?

Answer (score 2):

As per Bluetooth functionality, one would have to pair/unpair with the chosen device to switch to another system. It's worth noting that Apple by no means supports PC's to work with their accessories, and a quick search will show you plenty of people having a less-than-stellar experience trying to make it work. A more appropriate long-term solution is a wired keyboard and a KVM to switch between systems.

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth Apple Wireless Keyboard is able to be connected and used with a Win PC as long as the Win PC supports bluetooth.

Comment: what does it take to switch between the two? How easy is it?

Comment: If both Mac and Win PC are turned on, you need to pair and unpaid the bluetooth keyboard (or turn on/off the bluetooth on the Mac or PC).  Otherwise, as @David said, a wired keyboard with a KVM is better choice.